# Regular expression help for URL

Tags: c#, regex, url-rewriting

I have a URL like this:

```
http://www.domain.com/sponsor/xxxxx/reo/news
```

It needs to end up being rewritten to:

```
http://www.domain.com/reo/news?brokerId=xxxxx
```

I'm terrible at regular expressions. How can I extrapolate the "xxxxxx" from the source URL and transform the string to the end result?

I don't really need much help creating the end result, that's pretty trivial, but if there's a nice, clean way to do it with RegEx versus raw string manipulation, that'd be nice to know about.

Comment: The was terrible at regex... until I took the time to learn how they work and practice using them. Weird huh?

Comment: Yes, regular expressions are on the list with the million other technical skills I'd like to improve with, spending time with my wife, my daughter, my other hobbies and my second job. :) I'm sure my wife will understand when I tell her regular expressions are more important. :P

Comment: Have you considered using the URI class instead of regex? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx

Comment: @Scott - Here is a [helpful tool](http://regexpal.com/). Take 15-30 minutes a week to write a few regular expressions and you'll be an expert in no time. I don't think your wife and daughter are that demanding are they? :) Heck I learned regular expressions between completing projects at my job.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll check it out. :)

Comment: @Scott - I hope I didn't sound too condescending in my first comment. It's just that I feel regex is such a useful tool that not knowing how to use them is like showing up at a construction site and not knowing how to use a hammer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `"http://([^/]+)/sponsor/([^/]+)/reo/news"` as your regexp.

Use and `"http://$1/reo/news?brokerId=$2"`as your replacement string.

I tried your example on [.NET Regex Tester](http://regexhero.net/tester/), and it produced the desired output.

Comment: I don't get the "http://$1/reo/news?brokerId=$2" part, this dollars, could somebody please provide Java code example?

Comment: He's using replacement for the placeholders $1 and $2 ($1 = domain, $2 = xxxxx). This replacement expression was written with C# in mind.

Comment: Ah, is there such place-holder feature in Java?

Comment: @Adam Yes, in Java you use `\1`, `\2`, and so on (the same way as use back references).